# Sublime Text regex: replace Strings with Gettext

Tags: regex, wordpress, sublimetext, gettext

I made a mistake writing a template page in Wordpress and so I put regular strings everywhere instead of Gettext calls. Now I should replace all strings in these specific constructs with Gettext calls.

Example:

```
displayDataRow($$fuelTypePacksName,'model-tech-wheels','Wheels');
displayDataRow($$fuelTypePacksName,'model-tech-curb-weight',__( 'Wheels', 'agr' ));
```

I haven't learned regex yet, sorry :(

Comment: What should be replaced??? What is your expected result?

Comment: Sorry. I'll try to be more clear. The first row in my example is the line of code without a Gettext call, the second one has a Gettext call in it.

So the `'Wheels'` part should be replaced with `__( 'Wheels', 'agr' )`. I need the regex because I don't have only the string 'Wheels' but also other strings in similar constructions (passed as displayDataRow() arguments).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to replace, but the pattern for finding the strings is

```
'[^']*'
```

So, if for example you want to replace `"hello world"` with `GetText("hello world")` you have to do

```
 find: ('[^']*')
  replace: GetText(\1)
```

Essentially, the parantheses added around the pattern mean "keep what you find", and `\1` means "replace with the first thing you found.